# how to call contexts.xml file in eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have created an eclipse plug-in with a view project. I have a contexts.xml file and i have configured it. Please refer the following code.

```xml
<contexts>
<context id="Help" title="Plug-in Help">
    <description>context help for the sample view</description>
    <topic href="resources/text.html" label="Context-sensitive help">
    </topic>
</context>
</contexts>
```

I have an html file named "text" under resources folder inside the plugin project.

```java
//Listener to invoke the help method of RepositoryAccessor class
bHelp.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseDown(MouseEvent arg0){

    Display display=PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay();
     Shell shell = new Shell(display);

     GridLayout grid11=new GridLayout(3,true);

     //Layout of controls inside the plugin view
     shell.setLayout(grid11);

   Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.NONE);

   PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().setHelp(text,"help");
   PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().displayHelp("help"); 
}
}
```

bHelp is a button. Once i run the eclipse plugin and click the bHelp button, i get a new shell window and i see only empty label.

Please suggest a method to  assign the html contents to the label created in the popup window(new shell).
[image]

At Step 1, i click Help Icon and a new shell is open. In Step 2, the label is still showing "sfsf" instead of the contents in "text.html".

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `org.eclipse.help.contexts` extension point to tell Eclipse about your contexts.xml:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.help.contexts"> 
  <contexts file="contexts.xml"/> 
</extension>
```

Also the `setHelp` call only registers the help for the control, it does not display the help. If you want to display a help context id use:

```java
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().displayHelp("your context id");
```

Note that the help system always opens its own view to display the help (or expands the dialog if you use `TrayDialog` or one of its subclasses).

So if you have a `Button` you would invoke the help with:

```java
button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter()
  {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e)
    {
      PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().displayHelp("your context id");
    }
  });
```

Comment: I have registered my contexts.xml with my plugin.xml

Comment: How do i call the help when i click the help icon. I tried the steps which you have mentioned above but it is not working, If any tutorial you can suggest me it would be of great help.

Comment: I have edited my code above. Please check and tell me where i made the mistake. When i click Help icon button a new pop-up window occurs and in that there is a textbox in which i intend to display the help description but that is not happening. Please help or give suggestions.

Comment: As I have already said the help system always uses its own window. It does not support displaying help in a Text control.